# Is it good to store relational database table as different index in elastic-search if yes then how to pass relationship in index

Tags: python, arrays, json, elasticsearch, logstash

For Example in my case, there are 3 postgres table which is being linked by primary key and sharing data.

1) Product Table - It contains all product value and price etc.

2.) Nutrients - It contains nutrients of that product which is having the duplicate primary key.

3.)Serving Size - It contains the quantity of serving size of the nutrients.

I transferred this data to elasticsearch after doing the join made it more complex.
So I want to transfer this data to elasticsearch with NDB_NO as document_id and under it, all data will come. I need help..
[please check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbDwg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

Sometimes, mirroring your database Tables in Elasticsearch makes sense. For example, if you want users to be able to search a list of nutrients by themselves, and a list of Products by themselves, having two Elasticsearch indicies is best.

However, what it sounds like you want, and is more common in the Elasticsearch world, is to combine data from your different tables when indexing into Elasticsearch. Because of the way full text search works, you often want to [denormalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data. Denormalization is usually an antipattern in the relational database world, but is often a best practice for Elasticsearch.

Here's an example, if you want users to be able to search for products that contain various nutrients, you might want to index your Product documents like this:

```
#change host to reflect your Elasticsearch server
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/products/_doc/1' -d '{
  "name": "Banana",
  "nutrients": ["potassium", "vitamin C", "copper"]
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/products/_doc/2' -d '{
  "name": "Rice",
  "nutrients": ["manganese", "copper"]
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/products/_doc/3' -d '{
  "name": "Orange",
  "nutrients": ["Vitamin C", "Thiamin"]
}'
```

*Please excuse my poor attempts at nutrition information*

As you can see, the names of the nurtients are often duplicated. However, this approach lets you use Elasticsearch's full-text search abilities to find any item that has a desired nutrient.

You would probably want to re-use IDs from your relational database for your products in Elasticsearch (or store them in another field), so that you can then go back to the "source" of your data for more information.